# Ionic push device register

Tags: ionic-framework

I followed all the instructions on Ionic's [guide](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push) for push notifications but registring users don't seems to work.

I added this code inside my $ionicPlatform.ready function:

```
$ionicPush.register().then(function(t) {
      return $ionicPush.saveToken(t);
    }, function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }).then(function(t) {
      console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
    });
```

I have breakpoints over both of the lines of the promise but it reaches to none of them.

Also after a minute in the app I'm getting this error:

> POST https://api.ionic.io/insights 422 (UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY) Ionic
>   Insights: Could not send insights. Error: UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY(…)

The app is running on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't put the right GCM project number when configuring $ionicCloudProvider.